# Working with dates in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, matlab-figure

How can I get MATLAB to display the dates and times on the x-axis of a plot?

I am trying to make a plot that shows the water level (WL) in cm over time, as illustrated in the image:

[image: Water level over time. indices on x-axis, water level on y-axis]

Right now, the x-axis of my plot just shows indices, but I want it to display the dates and times in the order: year, month, day, hour, minute. The format is not that important as long as it's readable and in that order. I also want to be able to control the ticks, so that the user won't be overwhelmed.

In MATLAB, I've been working with dates in the following way:

1. An array that contains the DATES in *yyyyMMddhhmm* format as numbers.
2. Multiple arrays that contain *yyyy, MM, dd* and so on.

WL and my DATES array have the same length, and they arranged so that `WL(i)` corresponds to `DATES(i)`. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
figure(1)
hold on
plot(WL)
xlabel('Date')
ylabel('WL [cm]')
```

Comment: If you only provide one vector to [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) then it can obviously only possibly know to plot it by index. Pass it two arguments. See: [Plot Dates and Durations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/plot-dates-and-durations.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `WL` and `DATES` looks like this:

```
WL = [6 4 5];
DATES = [201412241842
    201412251830
    201412261921];
```

You can do the following to convert `DATES` to `datetime` format:

```
dates = datetime(num2str(DATES),'InputFormat','yyyyMMddHHmm');
```

And then you just plot it:

```
plot(dates,WL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps:

1) convert your date/time values to [datenums](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

2) use [datetick](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to make your x-axis the way you want